# re-inserting a table record and updating an auto increment primary index

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I'm running MariaDB 5.5.56.

I'm looking to copy an entire row in a database, change one column, then insert the entire row back into the original database (I don't want to have to specify the individual fields because there's a lot of them).   The problem I'm running into is how to deal with an auto-increment/primary key column.

example:

```
create temporary table t_ownership like ownership;
insert into t_ownership (select * from ownership where name='x' LIMIT 1);
update t_ownership set id='something else';
insert into ownership (select * from t_ownership);
```

I have a column "recno" that is an auto-increment that will create a collision in the database when I try to re-insert the slightly changed record back into the original table.

Something like this seems to work but doesn't result in an insert:

```
insert into ownership (select * from t_ownership) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE recno=LAST_INSERT_ID(ownership.recno);
```

The above statement executes without error but does not add a row to table ownership.

So I think I'm close but not quite there...

What would be the best way to do this?   I'd like to avoid doing an insert where I manually specify field/values.  I just need to regenerate a new A.I. recno column on the insert.

Comment: The cleanest way would be to specify all fields, but couldn't you just set recno to NULL in t_ownership?

Comment: I thought about that.. I will try it and see if it works.

Comment: Yes!  That worked!     This will solve my problem, although I'm curious if there is any other work-around that I'm unaware of.

Comment: Added as an answer in case no others are presented.

Comment: Thanks!   this may be the best approach, but I'm also curious if there is another work around.  It's odd that there doesn't appear to be a way to get the next logical A.I. value without doing a separate database call.

Comment: Is `id` the `PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT`?  **WHY** do you want to change it???  Or are you trying to create a new record, similar to an old one?  The question is poorly phrased; please improve on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NULL values inserted into auto-incremented fields end up just getting the next auto-increment value, behaving equivalent to INSERTing without specifying the field; so you should be able to update the source (temp copy) to have NULL for that field.

However, one potential issue that could present itself in scenarios like yours is that the `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ... LIKE` could result in a table that would not allow you to set such fields to NULL; this would require you to either ALTER the temporary table, or create it in a more explicit manner. Either way, it now makes code/queries that do not specify columns even more reliant on knowing columns.

Personally, I would take this route in the first place.

```
INSERT INTO theTable([list all but the auto-inc column])
SELECT [list all but the auto-inc column, with any replacements or modifications desired]
FROM ...[original query]...
```

It accomplishes the task in one query, makes the queries more self documenting, and only at the cost of a little typing (most of which a decent database browser, or query builder, will do for you).

The only argument really in favor of your current approach is that the table involved can be changed without necessarily breaking your queries; but that begs the question of whether it would be better for such table changes to break the queries, forcing them to be re-examined. If it is not an issue, it is a minor revision; but the alternative is queries that continue to be valid that have the potential to cause unexpected behavior due to copying information they were never intended to.

Comment: actually this worked for me - I wasn't sure if I could set an auto-increment index to null but it did work.     The operative issue is, I don't want to have to specify each field because there are a ton of them and I only need to change 1-2 columns.

Comment: Is the temp table's recno field NULL after you update it to that? My worry would be the UPDATE SET NULL actually sets it to the temp table's next auto-increment value; which happens to be the same as the original table's...which if fine unless a record gets inserted into that table between your select from it and insert back into it. (But I've never tried updating an auto-inc to NULL, so I don't know how it actually behaves).

Comment: it set it to NULL... then when I copied to the original table, it created an A.I. value for that column, as is what I wanted  :)

I may have been able to get away with it because there was only one record in the database?   maybe internally it was a 0?